# Git rebase lot of conficts

Tags: git

I've create branch X from testing, now I want to merge branch X to master. I used command:
`git rebase origin/master -X theirs`
and i get response:

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
interactive rebase in progress; onto <<hash>>
Last commands done (3 commands done):
   pick <<secret>>
   pick <<secret>>
Next commands to do (569 remaining commands):
   pick <<secret>>
   pick <<secret>>
You are currently rebasing branch X on <<hash>>.
```

How can I extract only my changes from this branch?

Comment: What is the reason you are you using `-X theirs`? Also, how many commits do you have that you wish to merge into `master`? (I see the number 569 on the screen...) With many commits *that cause conflicts* you're probably better off either squashing them down to fewer commits prior to performing the branch rebase, or just skipping the branch rebase altogether and going for the merge.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that currently processed commit after resolving conflicts do not contain any changes. It may be result that same change has been submitted to both branches after "merge base" or conflict resolution leads to change which is equivalent to branch you are rebasing to (since you have selected option `-X theirs` this is most probable).

As a result git stop with warring to prevent committing something which is result of incorrect conflict resolution.

Things it proposes to resolve situation:

1. create commit without any changes (to save a description what should happen).
2. drop (skip) this commit since it is empty.
3. You can also decide something went wrong and drop rebase/cherry-pick to start from begging

When you will take option 1 or 2 rebase cherry-pick will continue with other commits.